# максимально ускорить получение ответа от сервера

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest

в сетевых технологиях я профан, но у меня есть потребность максимально уменьшить время отклика от стороннего сервера. Запросы шлются в виде GET и POST с использованием куков с авторизацией по https протоколу. можно ли как-то исключить из запроса все ssl проверки, чтобы ускорить время ответа от сервера, или "рукопожатие" применятся только при первом запросе, а в последующих не влияет на задержку (Если использовать WebRequest)? вот пример замеров скорости загрузки с помощью онлайн сервиса:
http://ping-admin.ru/free_test/result/15605792725jvp4xi310k7e6vv3ff17c.html
Из этого теста видно, что большая часть запроса тратится на ssl фиговину. Или может есть еще какие способы уменьшения времени отклика от сервиса?

Comment: Если сервер работает только по https, то вы можете подключиться к нему только по https.

Comment: При работе со сторонним сервером вы обязаны работать с ним по его правилам, даже если они вам не нравятся, альтернативы нет. Какую проблему в вашем приложении вы хотите решить уменьшив время отклика сервера?

Comment: @rdorn Да, моя основная задача уменьшить время отклико от стороннего сервера, чтобы я мог как можно быстрее отсылать и получать от него данные. меня например интересует вопрос: с какой периодичность происходит рукопожатие с сервером (т.е. как часта я буду тратить куче времени на ssl штуковины) используя webrequest. И я не пытаюсь устранить долгий отклик, а пытаюсь найти способ общаться с сервером на максимально допустимой скорости извне.

Comment: вы будете постоянно тратить время на ожидание шифрования отправляемых и расшифровки получаемых данных - это тоже часть SSL протокола. Так что в эту сторону копать не имеет смысла. К тому же, ваш пример выполняется очень быстро. Лучше смотрите в сторону выполнения запросов в асинхронном режиме, т.к. по множеству причин скорость может проседать в произвольные моменты времени, вне зависимости SSL это, простой HTTP или голый сокет.